# How to read data from dht11 using atmega328p

Tags: c, microcontroller, sensors, avr

Using IDE : AtmelStudio, uC = atmega328p, sensor DHT11

Im trying to read the values from DHT11. 
I have set the start signal

```
DDRC |= 1 << TEMP_SENZOR; //output
_delay_ms(2000); // wait for 2s according to datasheet
PORTC &= ~ (1 << TEMP_SENZOR); //set low for at least 18 ms
_delay_ms(20);
PORTC |= 1 << TEMP_SENZOR; // set high
```

Then i have set getResponse metod

```
DDRC &= ~ (1 << TEMP_SENZOR); // set for input
while(PINC & (1 << TEMP_SENZOR));
while(PINC & (1 << TEMP_SENZOR) == 0);
while(PINC & (1 << TEMP_SENZOR));
```

I have tried to code function several times, to get values but unfortunately i get some values that have nothing to do with reading from Proteus DHT11.

Im new to this, so sorry if question is trivial.

Comment: Note that `~` binds stronger than `<<` therfore `~1<<TEMP_SENZOR` is equal to `(~1)<<TMP_SENZOR` but you actually want `~(1<<TEMP_SENZOR)` i think.

Comment: @Osiris i forgot to put it but thx for pointing out

Comment: The data is send over a serial interface. I would recommend to read [this](http://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-set-up-the-dht11-humidity-sensor-on-an-arduino/) article as they also provide a library with read functions. (It is for arduino but it should be easy to translate it.)